# How to remove the basic conky installed on ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, conky

I have installed basic-conky using the following commands:

```
wget -O basic-conky-eth-u.zip http://goo.gl/n0Jlg
unzip basic-conky-eth-u.zip
sudo rm basic-conky-eth-u.zip
```

Now how do I remove it?

Even downloaded the startup script using these commands:

```
wget -O .start-conky http://goo.gl/6RrEw
chmod +x .start-conky
```

I don't want to continue with it. Can anyone tell how to remove it?

Comment: Looks as if you simply delete all the files you downloaded.

Comment: looks like it :)

Comment: Its unclear which are the files that have been downloaded.

Comment: @ahj.ashish that is because all the links are shortened, can you post where you found the instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can remove it and all config files by typing this command:

"sudo apt-get --purge remove package name"

In this case, run the following command on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove conky conky-all
```

Answer (score 1):

hello>>>>>go to (system tools) then click (synaptic package manager) will ask u put password (put it) click on top (search) then put (name program) and search it,will see it in list,will be active green color,,,,right click (mark for complete removal) on top Apply
will ask u password (put it) and will see it start remove (basic-conky)or any program u want remove it

:)